# Add props to a $$typeof: Symbol(react.element)

Tags: reactjs

I want to add extra props to a React element that has this value `$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)`. How can I do that? The component only renders when I have `{MyComponent}` and not when I have `<MyComponent />`, this makes it hard for me to add extra props. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React has a tool for that:

```
React.cloneElement(MyComponent, { extraProp: 'hey there' })
```

[React cloneElement docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement)